# Converting two regex into one in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that is responsible for the formatting of the text. When there are multiple blank rows it converts them to one, when there are white spaces and blank lines it converts them only to blank lines, because when there are white spaces and blank lines together the first convertion doesn't work. My code till looks like this:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"), "<br />", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/<br \/>(\s|<br \/>)+<br \/>/", "<br /><br />", $string);
echo $string;
```

How can i make the two line regex into one?

I tried with this, but it doesn't seem to work fine:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)(\s|(\r\n|\r|\n))+(\r\n|\r|\n)/", "<br /><br />", $string);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace any white space when there is a new line:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s*\r?\n/", "<br /><br />", $string);
```

Comment: Your regex will cut whitespace at the beginning of the last line (after the last CRLF). What if there's a stackoverflow-like code formatting?